# Diagnosing water heater error - Need help with diagram

Tags: schematics

I'm diagnosing an error in a water heater. The error code indicates that the error is related to the connectors X2. Between both connectors X2 there is this Symbol "/" with the number 5. I have marked it with slight yellow. What does this symbol indicate?

[image: Water heater]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slash indicates that the schematic line indicates a bus of five wires, rather than just a single wire. For the /5 example you call out, it means that all five pins on the X2 connector of item 1 are connected to the corresponding five pins of the X2 connector (item 13). If connector X2 is implicated in a troubleshooting guide, you may want to use a multimeter to ensure that all five pins of the cable still have continuity from one end to the other, and there are no short circuits between adjacent pins. This is in addition to any further measurements (e.g. of voltages on those pins) that the manual recommends.

Likewise, item 2 presumably has a single three-pin cable going to the three-pin connector X10 (item 12).

The /1 going to item 3 is a bit of an oddball - there's a single wire, and it's specifically called out as a single wire. The return for that signal might be chassis ground (given the dotted lines between that wire and ground on/near the X7 connector).

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the cable, you will see the /5 is connected to 5 pins (X2).  The /3 to 3 (X10) on the left and the /1 to 1 connector.  You should expect to see 5-pin, 3-pin and 1 pin connectors.

[image]

From BS60617:

> If a single line represents a group of conductors, the number of connections may be indicated either by adding as many oblique strokes or one stroke followed by the figure for the number of connections.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It means there are 5 wires (conductors) in that cable.

Answer (score -7):

The number of the wire indicates the AWG (American Wire Gauge) size of the wire, calculated as 40-(6*n+3), where n is the number you see in your schematic. So for 5 it is AWG 7, for 1 it is AWG 31 etc. AWG7 probably goes to a motor or another inductive load since it is a thick cable

Comment: Did you notice how many pins are at the other end of each of those cables? Coincidence? Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: AWG 35 is a very SMALL conductor, not large.  Please edit your answer with correct information so that I can remove my down vote.

Comment: Occam's razor suggests that wire gauges would be indicated using the standard AWG values, rather than an unusual formula with arbitrary constants.

Comment: I have updated the formula and calculations, now AWG7 is big and goes to motor

Comment: I won't pile on the downvotes, but this answer is definitely wrong.

Comment: Complete nonsense.

Comment: You should delete your answer.... It's totally wrong....    "A' for effort though!